# How does scheduling work?

Tags: cron, windows-task-scheduler

How do programs designed for scheduling (e.g. Task Scheduler in Windows, cron in Unix systems) know that it "is time" for them to run a certain scheduled command or script?

I imagine it's not something like a timed function checking the system clock every second or minute. Is there some kind of trigger being activated when a time stamp corresponding to a certain planned task is reached?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Multi-user_capability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably varies between OSes. For cron, the [crond manpage](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_crond.htm) indicates that there's a daemon running in the background which activates itself every minute to check if there's a task that needs to be run.

Windows also has a service that does this according to this [support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308558), though I have no idea of its granularity. Its likely it works similarly.

Comment: Hmm, then I guess it does wake up every minute to check if there are any commands or scripts to run.